# App Crashes While Performing Segue From MapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, segue

An app I'm developing houses a map view and everything is functioning. I can interact with the map and so on.

However, when I tap a button I placed under the map view to perform a segue into the settings view with just some labels and switches, I get the Swift's optional unwrapping error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The error happens on the map view that I've created for the initial view and when I check the debug console the map view seems to be nil as the error message relates.

Why does the segue care about the map view being deallocated and throws an exception? How can I resolve this issue?

**My Code & Storyboard:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.configureFloorPlan()
}

func configureFloorPlan() {
    ...
    // the crash happens at the following line of code when I press the button
    mapView.addOverlay(HideBackgroundOverlay.hideBackgroundOverlay(), level: .AboveRoads)
    ...
}
```

The segue is initiated when I press the info button in the bottom left corner of the initial view controller.

[image]

When I removed the destination view controller's class, the crash resolves. It's interesting since currently that class in empty.

Comment: Seeing your code will help us to understand what's going on

Comment: Please show us your segue code in your map view controller, and also your destination view controller class.

Comment: Please see my edit. @u54r

Comment: We still need more code. Where in your class do you set mapView? Please show the entire class. Also, where do you create your HideBackgroundOverlay object? Your mapView might be nil, or your HideBackgroundOverlay might be nil. It is not possible to tell with the code given.

Comment: @MrBeardsley Here is the full class file of the initial view which houses the map view and the button of the segue. http://pastebin.com/63RLamhN

Comment: If you remove the segue and it the error goes away then there is something wrong with the segue that you set up.

Comment: I removed the navigation controller, directly linked to the view I was trying to get and added a navigation bar in order to coordinate view actions and it all works now.